# How to display the content.field_xxx in twig (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal-7, twig

I have added a custom field field_instruction (plain text field) in a new content type.

I would like to display the field like `{{ content.field_instruction }}` in node.html.twig. However, it failed.

I tried `{{ content.field_instruction[0] }}` or `{{ content.field_instruction.value }}`, it does not success.

Can anyone advise me how to display this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render a field's default value inside node.html.twig, try use a Twig variable as in `{{ node.field_some_name.value }}`.